# How to upload a file from javascript fetch api to external system

Tags: javascript, salesforce, integration, fetch-api

```
        var header = boundary +
        "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + this.fileData[0].Title + " \"" + 
        "\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream" ; 
        var footer = boundary; 
        const body = '{"name":' + this.fileData[0].VersionData + '}';
        fetch(uploadEndPointURL,{
            method: 'POST',
            // mode: 'no-cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            Body: btoa(header+body+footer),
            
        headers: { 
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Authorization': 
            "Bearer "+this.accessToken,
            'Content-Type': undefined,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': uploadEndPointURL,
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE',
          //  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'origin,X-Requested-With,content-type,accept',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
        }
        }).then(function(response){ 
            console.log('response--',response)  
        }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error)); 
        });
```

I am using this code to upload a file to BOX, but getting '415' error in console. I am doing this from js file LWC.